# Can not load local html file in WKWebView Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I used this code before - everything worked

```
let localfilePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "nameFile", withExtension: "html")
let myRequest = NSURLRequest(url: localfilePath!)

WebView.loadRequest(myRequest as URLRequest)
self.view.addSubview(WebView)
```

Help please - now I use `WKWebView`.

How to open a local html file in the `WKWebView`? Thank you

Answer (score 7):

```
import WebKit

@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!


let htmlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "NameFolder/FileName", ofType: "html")

 let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlPath!)

 let request = URLRequest(url: url)
 webView.load(request)
```

*Do not forget to put your folder with the files here*
[image: Do not forget to put your folder with the files here]

Answer (score 0):

WKWebView has a method specific for [loading local urls](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414973-loadfileurl). No need to use a URLRequest, just pass your local file url. Btw naming a url object 
localfilePath is misleading. I suggest changing it to localfileURL.

Comment: Hello, you can see an example - how it will look, thanks